# How can I increase mouse cursor speed?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, speed

I'm using a Dell Branded Mouse in my Windows7 64bit Operating System.

I've Increased the pointer speed to full from control panel but it nevertheless seems to be slow enough to work with. Could anyone tell me whether there is any other way to increase its pointer speed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning off visual effects? The repainting needed to show effects could effect perceived performance when moving a mouse.
From the control panel, select "system" or in explorer, right click on "Computer" and pick "Properties". Then "Advanced system settings", then "Advanced" tab and finally click the "Settings..." button. Try turning them all off at first to see if it makes a difference on your pc. Then add back what you can live with.

Comment: jdh it didn't work at all